# Change part of theme according to time of day

Tags: 8, theming

In Drupal 8, I'm trying to change part of a twig template according to time of day.

For instance, if in one of my twig templates I have:

```
<img src="img_during_the_day.jpg"/>
```

Where and what do I need to change to have it produce

```
<img src="img_during_the_day.jpg"/>
<!-- or -->
<img src="img_during_the_night.jpg"/>
```

according to server time?

I was thinking of doing it passing a variable to my twig template and then something like:

```
{{ if (variable == 'day') }}
    <img src="img_during_the_day.jpg"/>
{{ else }}
    <img src="img_during_the_night.jpg"/>
{{ endif }}
```

But I don't know how to pass a `$variable` to the template. Also, if I were to do this in a module, what `hook` would I have to alter to achieve this?

The idea would be to use PHP's `date` object to find out the current time to then change the value of a certain `$variable` in a hook, and said variable would be available to work in twig with in the above pseudo-syntax.

Can anyone share some pointers on where to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define new variables in the array `$variables` in preprocess.

Assuming this is the page template:

**modules/mymodule/mymodule.module:**

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ( ... ) {
    $variables['daynight'] = 'day';
  }
  else {
    $variables['daynight'] = 'night';
  }
}
```

Then use the variable in your twig code:

```
{{ if (daynight == 'day') }}
    <img src="img_during_the_day.jpg"/>
{{ else }}
    <img src="img_during_the_night.jpg"/>
{{ endif }}
```

Or shorter:

```
<img src="img_during_the_{{ daynight }}.jpg"/>
```

You will get some problems with caching. In drupal and in proxies and browsers. So this is probably not a server but a client side solution.

Comment: +1 for factoring the caching issues, I totally forgot about that. Guess I'll figure something out with JS, then.

Comment: But, on the other hand, can't caching be disabled for a certain page? At least at (my) server level?

Comment: Nearly positive you can update `$variables['#cache']` in the preprocess to add any ages/contexts you need.